# Passing data from a popup using EventListener and postMessage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, oauth-2.0, react-router

I am working on an oAuth login, it works fine but the entire process of the redirection to the authorization and the response is happening on the same page.
What i am trying to do is to open it in a popup.

In order to achieve this i have to add an EventListener in the parent page (where the "connect using github" button is, for example). Here is the code:

```
let popup = window.open(window.location.origin+`/socialProcess?site=github`, width=600, height=600);
popup.addEventListener("message", (response) => {
        if (response.origin !== window.location.origin) {
            return;
        }
        let data = response.data;
        if (data.success) {
            alert(this.state.userName + " account accessed successfully");
        }
    }, false);
```

In the child's page which is loaded by the route `/socialProcess`, i first reload the popup page to the social networks oAuth url and after the process of the authorization the response URI returns back to `/socialProcess` (all happens in the same popup window).
Using the received data (after processing it) i then try to send it to the parent listener function in a 3 different ways like so:

```
window.opener.postMessage({success: this.state.success}, this.state.page);
window.postMessage({success: this.state.success}, this.state.page);
parent.postMessage({success: this.state.success}, this.state.page);
```

But it seems that the listener's function is not being triggered.

I think the issue is with the popup page self reload when loading the social oauth page then the response URI.
Because if i add `window.postMessage({success: true}, this.state.page);` before the reload my parent page gets the data.

What confuses me the most is that if i add `window.opener.location.reload();` under the `postMessage` (after the popup reload) my parent page does reload which means it does remember who opened it so why does `window.opener.postMessage({success: this.state.success}, this.state.page);` not working? is the listener just die when the popup reloads?

What am i doing wrong? is there an other way of doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue.
First of all here is the correct postMessage: `window.postMessage`.

In my example i passed `window.postMessage({success: this.state.success}, this.state.page);` the `this.state.page` value has to be a string since the listener is expecting to receive a 'message'.

That means that i have to convert any object to string using Json stringify for example.

Doing that and passing my values as a string (then parsing it) solved my issue.